# Batch Tween/ Fade Function in Photoshop (Fade between frames)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif

I have a series of sequential .bmp images (exported from ArcMap--a mapping software). I would like to have these images fade between each other and, ultimately, export as a gif. Is there a simplified way to batch the Tween function to apply to all 50 frames in my dataset? Or can you recommend a better way to get the desired result?

Comment: Can you attach the snapshot  of initial(first) and final(Last) snapshot?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i think the best way to do dat.. use gimp software other than photoshop..

its easy and opensourse.. and more resorse ful

meanwhile i found this link in wiki how.. in thre tell how to make simple animation.. like loading in while instalin win xp..

but if u use this method u can do it ur self to do what u want.. i also try dat
in this link it discribe step by step how to do dat.. just try it..

in there make simple gif animation.. but frogt about basik step and just do that ur pics..thanks

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Animated-GIF-Image-with-GIMP

Comment: Hi Hasaru, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!